# libdvm.so location

Tags: android, macos, linker, android-ndk

I have a linker error when trying to build my JNI application:

undefined reference to `JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs'

From [this](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.ndk/1470) thread I figured out that I need to use libdvm.so to resolve the issue. But I can't figure out where the libdvm.so is located.

I'm using Android NDK r6 on MacOS.

Comment: The link is broken.  Would still be of interest though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`libdvm.so` is part of [Android's full build](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/opensource/download#TOC-Initializing-a-Repo-client) and it is available in build output folder at:

```
out/target/product/*/symbols/system/lib/libdvm.so
```

Comment: But where is ndk/out/ located ?

Comment: I've figured it out myself. Thanks anyway. It is also can be found at /system/lib/libdvm.so